# The Nodejs <core.pid> file is created only on a node

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, devops, pm2

I have a production workspace where the application is vue.js using 'nuxt' and is daemonized using pm2. Being a high-availability architecture, there are two identical EC2 instances under the load balancer.

The problem is that the disk space is filling up on only one node because of these <core.pid> files in the project folder.

Every time I have to manually delete the <core.pid> files, but I want an answer why the same application on the second node does not create any such files.

I did some research and found that these are memory dumps and as a workaround, I set the core soft limit to 0 using the "ulimit -c 0" command.

File permissions are '775' for the project directory however, I wonder why the core files are not created on the second node.

Thank you in advance for any information you can provide.

FYI: Below is the pm2 log:

```
PM2        | 2023-03-29T07:47:28: PM2 log: App [npm:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2023-03-29T07:47:28: PM2 log: pid=28236 msg=process killed
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the PM2 logs: PM2 logs all output from your Node.js application, including any error messages or stack traces. Check the PM2 logs on both servers to see if there are any errors or differences in behavior between the two servers.
2. Check system resources: Check the system resources (CPU, memory, etc.) on both servers to see if one server is under more load than the other. If one server is under heavy load, it may be more likely to crash and generate a core.pid file.

Comment: there are free memory or cpu available on both the servers, and i can see below logs from npm error log on both node
<pre>
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
</pre>

Comment: the --max-old-space-size is 2gb im using